# VB.NET Read Text File Every Two Minutes

Tags: vb.net

I am pretty new to VB.NET and I am trying to create a timer to read a line from a text file every two minutes. I have my code for reading the text file which is all good, but the timer part has just confused me as I have read so many different ways to use a timer.

I want to start the timer when the form loads, read the text file, wait two minutes and then run the same code again to read the text file. Any help on the simplest method for this would be GREATLY appreciated.

Comment: You add a Timer to your project, set the interval, and write an event handler to call your code that reads the file. In your form's Load event, you enable the timer. What part of that specifically are you having problems with?

Comment: Don't use a timer, it'll clog your UI. Use a [backgroundworker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead.

Comment: @TheBlueDog and how do you plan to resolve the two minutes interval without a Timer?

Comment: [FileSystemWatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Thanks for all of the comments... The code below is just what I was looking for. I wouldn't mind hearing other thoughts as I am trying to learn.  Backgroundworker? I have not used before.

Comment: @Steve: Personally, I'd have the worker loop with a sleep in between.

Comment: Use a `System.Threading.Timer` instead. This is run asynchronously wrt the UI thread. `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` events are raised on the UI thread. Especially if you aren't doing any operations on UI elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that this is a Windows Forms application....

```
Public Class Form1

    Dim WithEvents MyTimer As New System.Windows.Forms.Timer

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        MyTimer.Enabled = True
        MyTimer.Interval = 120000
    End Sub

    Private Sub `MyTimer_Elapsed`() Handles MyTimer.Tick
        ' Your code for reading the file goes here
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Thanks DWRoelands... this is exactly what I was looking for. And simple. Much appreciated